# cat files from pipe

Tags: bash, cat, join

I have to join files to one original file, which was split. There is a catalog, in which there are a lot of files,but no every is necessary. I have file with md5sum, which contain md5sum files I have to join.

```
join -1 1 -2 1 tmp sumpos | sort -k2,2 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs cat > result
```

tmp - sorted md5sum
sumpos - sorted md5sum which I found in the catalog

It is a task from studies and I think our lecturer don't want to xargs here, so is a way to do this without xargs?

Answer (score 0):

If you just drop the last pipe, xargs and cat it should work.
It would look like this:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 tmp sumpos | sort -k2,2 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr '\n' ' ' > result
```

Comment: No there are only names of the files.

Comment: Try to add `| cat - ` right before `> result`